# Ajax POST to api returning 500 (internal server errror) on this jquery line: xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to send an object to an api with ajax, how do I solve this issue?

Here is my javascript code:

```
var order = {

    ClientId: 0,

    products: []

};



document.querySelector('.btn-order').addEventListener('click', function () 

{

    var answer = window.confirm("?");

    if (answer) {

        orden.ClientId = document.querySelector('.client').value;

        console.log(order);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(order));

        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',

            url: '/Orders/Create1',

            data: JSON.stringify(order),

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',



            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (result) {

                alert('success');

            },

            error: function (result) {

                alert(result.responseText);

            }


        });

    }

});
```

And this is the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Create([FromBody]Order order)

{

    return Json(new { msg = "Success" });

}

Model classes:

public class Order

{

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public List<ProductsOrder> products { get; set; } 

}



public class ProductsOrder

{

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal subtotal { get; set; }

}
```

The server is returning an error, this is the browsers response:

> POST http://localhost:9019/Orders/Create 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> send @ jquery.js:9837
>
> ajax @ jquery.js:9434
>
> (anonymous) @ Sell.js:30

Answer (score 0):

```
order.ClientId = document.querySelector('.client').value;
```

You need check `document.querySelector('.client').value` is number value or not, may be it is string empty or undefiend and when send it to controller. `Model Binding` can not cast to int value.

The 500 (Internal Server Error) occur at controller action source code.
To prevent casting issue, you can change `int ClientId` to `int? ClientId`

```
public class Order
{
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public List<ProductsOrder> products { get; set; } 
}
```